# Best practice for presenting classifier accuracy using cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, model-evaluation, accuracy

I have a classifier whose classification accuracy I must present. Of course, I could just do e.g. a single 90/10 train/test split and report the test accuracy. However, my dataset is fairly small, so I'm worried the accuracy will fluctuate quite a bit depending on the split.

My question is: what is the best practice for presenting accuracy in this case? Should I perform a cross-validation and report the mean/stds of the test accuracies? Is it more appropriate to just do a large number of independent splits? Some third option?